# Queens placement

Tags: c, recursion, chess

The code below is intended to be a learning material for high school intermediate programming class, as an introduction to recursion and backtracking. I was thinking of rook placement and found it too boring. I was also thinking of unique queen placements and found it missing the point.

The code works (verified against [OEIS A000170](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C0%2C0%2C2%2C10%2C4%2C40%2C92&language=english&go=Search)).

Pupils are comfortable with C basics.

Seeking advice on clarity, and optimization (as long as it doesn't obscure clarity). Particularly, a good replacement for `nw_se` and `ne_sw` as names for diagonals.

I know I'd better test the `calloc` return value and put my `if`s on a separate line.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    long size;
    bool * ranks;
    bool * nw_se;
    bool * ne_sw;
} BoardState;

BoardState * board_state_init(long size)
{
    BoardState * bs = malloc(sizeof(*bs));

    bs->size = size;
    bs->ranks = calloc(size, sizeof(bs->ranks[0]));
    bs->nw_se = calloc(2*size - 1, sizeof(bs->nw_se[0]));
    bs->ne_sw = calloc(2*size - 1, sizeof(bs->ne_sw[0]));

    return bs;
}

void board_state_delete(BoardState * bs) {
    free(bs->ranks);
    free(bs->nw_se);
    free(bs->ne_sw);
    free(bs);
};

bool board_state_square_attacked(BoardState * bs, long file, long rank)
{
    if (bs->ranks[rank]) return true;
    if (bs->nw_se[bs->size - (file - rank)]) return true;
    if (bs->ne_sw[2*bs->size - 1 - (file + rank)]) return true;
    return false;
}

void board_state_set(BoardState * bs, long file, long rank, bool occupy)
{
    bs->ranks[rank] = occupy;
    bs->nw_se[bs->size - (file - rank)] = occupy;
    bs->ne_sw[2*bs->size - 1 - (file + rank)] = occupy;
}

long place_queens(BoardState * bs, long file)
{
    long placements = 0;
    if (file == bs->size) return 1;

    for (long rank = 0; rank < bs->size; ++rank) {
        if (board_state_square_attacked(bs, file,  rank)) continue;

        board_state_set(bs, file, rank, true);
        placements += place_queens(bs, file + 1);
        board_state_set(bs, file, rank, false);
    }
    return placements;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    long max_board_size = (argv[1] == 0)? 9: strtol(argv[1], 0, 0);

    for (long board_size = 1; board_size < max_board_size; ++board_size) {
        BoardState * bs = board_state_init(board_size);
        long placements = place_queens(bs, 0);
        board_state_delete(bs);
        printf("%ld: %ld\n", board_size, placements);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get this output: 1: 1
2: 0
3: 0
4: 2
5: 10
6: 4
7: 40
8: 92
which seems wrong to me. (0 queens for 2x2 board?)

Comment: It is correct: there are 0  ways to place 2 queens on a 2x2 board.

Comment: `long max_board_size = (argv[1] == 0)? 9: strtol(argv[1], 0, 0);` will lead to undefined behaviour if there are no arguments. You should always test `argc` before, especially at learning materials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's pretty good. However since it's teaching I would stick to C89 so that student's aren't surprised when they try to use Visual Studio on their own machines. This means no declaration inside `for`-statements and no `bool`-header file.

There's always opinions about indentation and formatting. I would prefer that you've spaces between operators and that `if`-bodies are on their own line.

I would also like the three `if` statements after each other to become one. It's easier to read since the body of the `if` statement are the same for all three `if` statements.

I don't see why you're using `long` instead of `int`. Is there any reason?  From what I can see, an `int` should be enough here.

The `nw_se` was I first going to rename `a1_h8` to be familiar with chessboard navigation, since all squares have a name, but you seldom talk about direction. However this idea falls since you can have bigger or smaller chessboards. Hence I do think that your naming is good enough, if not the best possible there is.

I also changed the check for `boardsize` from `<` to `<=`. If I give 2 as an input I would want to see the result from board sized 1 and 2, not just 1 as in your example. This also lets the default value to be 8 instead of 9 which make more sense, since "everybody" knows that there's 8 rows on a Chess board.

A bit curious: why are you using `_` for variables and camelCase for types?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int size;
    short * ranks;
    short * nw_se;
    short * ne_sw;
} BoardState;

BoardState * board_state_init(int size)
{
    BoardState * bs = malloc(sizeof(*bs));

    bs->size = size;
    bs->ranks = calloc(size, sizeof(bs->ranks[0]));
    bs->nw_se = calloc(2 * size - 1, sizeof(bs->nw_se[0]));
    bs->ne_sw = calloc(2 * size - 1, sizeof(bs->ne_sw[0]));

    return bs;
}

void board_state_delete(BoardState * bs) {
    free(bs->ranks);
    free(bs->nw_se);
    free(bs->ne_sw);
    free(bs);
};

short board_state_square_attacked(BoardState * bs, int file, int rank)
{
    if (bs->ranks[rank] ||
        bs->nw_se[bs->size - (file - rank)] ||
        bs->ne_sw[2 * bs->size - 1 - (file + rank)])
            return 1;

    return 0;
}

void board_state_set(BoardState * bs, int file, int rank, short occupy)
{
    bs->ranks[rank] = occupy;
    bs->nw_se[bs->size - (file - rank)] = occupy;
    bs->ne_sw[2 * bs->size - 1 - (file + rank)] = occupy;
}

int place_queens(BoardState * bs, int file)
{
    int placements = 0;
    int rank;

    if (file == bs->size)
            return 1;

    for (rank = 0; rank < bs->size; rank++) {
        if (board_state_square_attacked(bs, file,  rank))
                continue;

        board_state_set(bs, file, rank, 1);
        placements += place_queens(bs, file + 1);
        board_state_set(bs, file, rank, 0);
    }
    return placements;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int max_board_size = (argv[1] == 0) ? 8 : strtol(argv[1], 0, 0);
    int board_size;

    for (board_size = 1; board_size <= max_board_size; board_size++) {
        BoardState * bs = board_state_init(board_size);
        int placements = place_queens(bs, 0);
        board_state_delete(bs);
        printf("%ld: %ld\n", board_size, placements);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (x) return 1; return 0;` would't be better written as `return x`?

Comment: "I would stick to C89" - **NO!**  There is no good reason for not using the nice things C99 or C11 gives you, besides being able to use the crappy Visual Studio C compiler (which *does support some C99 features anyways*).

Comment: It has been 15 years since C99, and 25 years since C89!

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini not sure it's easier to understand, but it's definitely better. I missed it.